# Jar file execution issue?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, executable-jar

I am using this command to run my jar file

```
 java -cp otpreq.jar com.otp.req.SendRequest
```

and its giving error-:

```
 Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/RequestEntity
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.RequestEntity
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Why this error is coming I can't figure out .

I checked the Library and org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/RequestEntity is a Interface.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the http-client.jar:

```
java -cp otpreq.jar:http-client.jar com.otp.req.SendRequest
```

If O.S is windows, replace : by ;

Note: the newest httpclient is not located at apache commons, but at [apache http components](http://hc.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to include all the supporting jars in class path (command line itself).

Or bind all your supporting jars inside otpreq.jar.

Either one of these will solve this issue.

Comment: I am exporting whole project as JAR file in eclipse .. will it not bind all the supporting jars inside the otpreq.jar

Comment: @Mudit, by default, IDE will bind all the jars if source is exported. Please check the these things - 1).classpath file inside otpreq.jar. 2) check whether you added libraries from external path 3) try to give all the libraries in class path (-cp) in command line.